# Is there a way to hide "<form method="post"" elements from accessible readers?

Tags: html, asp.net

As the title stated, is there a way to hide `form method="post" action="./" id="webform"` or `input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" ...` from accessible readers?

In the same Vein, what is the purpose of those elements? Would it go against accessibility for those elements to be present inside the page source?

Comment: What is your purpose for hiding them?

Comment: Apparently it goes against accessibility for them to be visible to a sighted user? Please correct me if I'm wrong on that.